# ¿Cómo inhabilitar un entry en customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa con Python y CustomTkinter y necesito inhabilitar un *Entry* para evitar algunos problemas.
Se como hacerlo con Tkinter:

```
entry1.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
entry2.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

Así fue como deshabilité los *entry* en Tkinter, pero para CustomTkinter es distinto, ¿alguien sabe si es posible inhabilitarlo?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrias agregar un un ejemplo del codigo que intentas usar? Lo digo porque si te refieres a impedir que el usuario ingrese algo, el `Entry` se deshabilita exactamente igual que en Tkinter, con la opción `state`.

Comment: entry1.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    entry2.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

Comment: Asi fue como deshabilité los entry en tkinter, como se haría en customtkinter???

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento para habilitar/deshabilitar la entrada de texto a un *Entry* de CustomTkinter no difiere de la forma de hacerlo en Tkinter; establecer la opción `state` al valor correspondiente:

- `tkinter.NORMAL`/`customtkinter.NORMAL`/`"normal"` -> habilita el entry
- `tkinter.DISABLED`/`customtkinter.DISABLED`/`"disabled"` -> deshabilita el entry

a través del método `Entry.configure()`. Es decir, para deshabilitar un *entry* cualquiera de estas tres variantes es valida:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

entry = ctk.CTkEntry(...)
entry.configure(state=ctk.DISABLED)
```

---

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

entry = ctk.CTkEntry(...)
entry.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

---

```
import customtkinter as ctk

entry = ctk.CTkEntry(...)
entry.configure(state="disabled")
```

Ademas, puedes deshabilitarlo al inicio usando el argumento `state` del constructor:

```
entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=root, state=ctk.DISABLED)
```

Un ejemplo completo reproducible:

```
import customtkinter as ctk


class App(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.entry = ctk.CTkEntry(
            master=self,
            state=ctk.DISABLED  # Deshabilitado al inicio
            )
        self.entry.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
        self.change_entry_state_btn = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self,
            text="Habilitar Entry",
            command=self.on_change_entry_state
            )
        self.change_entry_state_btn.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

    def on_change_entry_state(self):
        if self.entry.cget("state") == ctk.NORMAL:
            self.entry.configure(state=ctk.DISABLED)
            self.change_entry_state_btn.configure(text="Habilitar Entry")
        else:
            self.entry.configure(state=ctk.NORMAL)
            self.change_entry_state_btn.configure(text="Deshabilitar Entry")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```